# Spring Dependency Injection into serializable beans

Tags: java, spring, serialization, dependency-injection

I have a service class which is not serializable and a bean which must be serializable but must have access to this service class:

```
class SomeBean implements Serializable
{
    private StuffFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    public SomeBean(StuffFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public getOther()
    {
        return this.factory.getSomeOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because now the `SomeBean` class is no longer serializable. What is the correct way to solve this in Spring? When I make the `factory` field transient then I loose the injected factory instance on deserialization, or not? And when I make the `StuffFactory` also serializable then this class will no longer be a singleton because each `SomeBean` instance will have it's own factory after deserialization then.

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of context for this *magic* to work.

One ugly way I can think of is a static `ThreadLocal` holding the `ApplicationContext` - it's how the spring-security works using `SecurityContextHolder`.

But the best if You'd be able to externalize the logic that requires the `StuffFactory` to some kind of singleton `SomeBeanService`, i.e.:

```
public class SomeBeanService {
    @Autowired
    private StuffFactory stuffFactory;

    public void doWithSomeBean(SomeBean bean) {
        // do the stuff using stuffFactory here
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The whole point in above alternative to `ThreadLocal` is to get rid of the dependency on `StuffFactory` from `SomeBean` completely. This should be possible, but will require changes in architecture. The *separation of concerns* (one of, not only Spring, basic rules) implies that it might be a good idea to let `SomeBean` be a simple *data transfer object* and the business logic to be moved to service layer.

If You'll be unable to achieve this, than the only way is using some kind of `static` context (as Ralph also said). The implementation of such context may involve using a `ThreadLocal`. This would allow to access the `ApplicationContext` to get the `StuffFactory`, but it's almost as ugly as global variables, so avoid it if possible.

**Update2:**

I just saw Your comment, that `SomeBean` is stored in HTTP session, and hence the serialization/deserialization issue. Now even more I advice to change Your design and remove the dependency. Make `SomeBean` a simple DTO, as small as possible to avoid overloaded sessions. There should be no logic requiring access to singleton Spring beans inside the `SomeBean`. Such logic should be placed in the controller or service layer.

Comment: But then I have to inject this SomeBeanService instead. Or do you mean accessing it without spring? Then this is somewhat similar to the Service Delegator pattern which is normally used by non-managed beans. But my `SomeBean` is spring-managed so I'd hoped that Spring has some magic for handling transient dependencies. Well, if no better solution pops up I guess I have to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Java provide a way to control the serialization and deserialization by implementing the two methods:

- `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;`
- `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;`

So you can change the write to store the bean without the reference to the service and later one while reading the object "inject" the reference again.

@see
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

You *MUST* create the instance in `readObject` as bean. If you only use a simple `new` it will not become a bean.
Therefore you need access to the Spring Context, for example via a static method.
May the best way is to use a bean factory to create the new instance.

---

An other way you can try to make the instance a spring bean is using `@Configurable` but that requires real AspectJ.

Comment: But how can I get the `stuffFactory` instance in the `readObject` method to reinitialize the dependency? This dependency is injected automatically by Spring when the bean is created. I have no application context available in the readObject method to get the bean manually from there. I hoped for some Spring magic to handle this.

Comment: @kayahr: see my extended answer

Comment: But a Spring bean normally doesn't know spring at all so it's not a good idea to get the application context via a static method. When I do this then I simply can drop the whole dependency injection idea and  access the `StuffFactory` via a static `getInstance` method or something like this.

Comment: Sorry but storing a bean is not a good idea at all, so you need to do some compromise. -- Second: this statement "Spring bean normally doesn't know spring at all" is may true for business beans, but not for infrastructure components. And what you do here is mixing infrastructure in an normal business bean. -- Anyway you can mask that strong spring dependency/access by annotation the class with `@Configurable`

Comment: @Ralph: For `@Configured` will load time weaving be enough? Or will it require compile time weaving? Will the `SomeBean` still be serializable when weaved?

Comment: @Roadrunner: 1) "For @Configured will load time weaving be enough?" I am not sure, but I expect hat load time weaving is enough, but I am not sure. -- Simply ask a new question at stack overflow. 2) If you "override" `writeObject` and `readObject` then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a `SomeBeanFactory`:

```
class SomeBeanFactory {
    @Autowired
    private StuffFactory stuffFactory;

    public SomeBean deserialize(...) {
        SomeBean someBean = ...;
        someBean.setStuffFactory(stuffFactory);
        return someBean;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to create a setter for `factory` in `SomeBean`.

Comment: Serialization and Deserialization is done by the web container (The SomeBean instance is somewhere in the HTTP session) so I can't delegate deserialization to a factory.

Answer (score 0):

A re-think of your architecture is potentially practical in this scenario. If you can isolate the data that needs to be serialized into a simple data transfer object (DTO), then it should be possible to provide a wrapper to that DTO that itself can contain dependencies to other beans.

For example:

```
public interface IDataBean {
    void setSomething(String someData);
}

// This is your session bean - just a plain DTO
public class MyDataBean implements IDataBean, Serializable {

   private String someData;

   public void setSomething( String someData ) {
      this.someData = someData;
   }
}

// This is the wrapper that delegates calls to a wrapped MyDataBean.
public class MyDataBeanWithDependency() implements IDataBean {

    private SomeOtherService service;

    private MyDataBean dataBean;

    public SimpleDataBeanWithDependency(MyDataBean dataBean, SomeOtherService service) {
       this.dataBean = dataBean;
       this.service = service;
    }

    public void setSomething(String someData) {
       // Here we make a call to the service to perform some specific logic that may, for example, hit a DB or something.
       String transformedString = service.transformString(someData);
       dataBean.setSomething(transformedString);
    }
}

public class SomeService {

    // This is a Spring session scoped bean (configured using <aop:scoped-proxy/>)
    @Autowired
    private MyDataBean myDataBean;

    // Just a plain singleton Spring bean
    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    public IDataBean getDataBean() {
         return new MyDataBeanWithDependency(myDataBean, someOtherService); 
    }
}
```

Sorry for all the code! However, let me try to explain what I mean here. If you always retrieve the session bean via a service (in this case SomeService), you have the option of creating a wrapper around the session bean. This wrapper can contain any bean dependencies (autowired into SomeService) that you may wish to use as part of performing logic alongside the session bean.

The neat thing about this approach is that you can program to an interface as well (see IDataBean). This means that, if you, for example, had a controller that obtains the data bean from the service, it makes unit testing/mocking very clean.

Possibly, an even cleaner approach from the code perspective, would be for MyDataBeanWithDependency to be registered in the spring container using "request" scope. So you could just autowire that bean directly into SomeService. This would essentially transparently deal with the instantiation so you don't need to manually instantiate MyDataBeanWithDependency from within the service.

Hopefully I've done enough to explain myself here!